# Specifying the protocol to fetch a bower dependency

Tags: angularjs, git, jenkins, bower, jwt

I'm relying on angular-jwt (https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt)

In my bower.json I have this:

```
"dependencies": {
...
    "angular-jwt": "~0.0.9"
```

When I deploy to a Jenkins build machine that do not have access to github through the git protocol I get this error:

```
[ERROR] bower angular-jwt#~0.0.9 ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt.git",
```

exit code of #128 fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 192.30.252.128]: errno=Connection refused

So is it possible to tell Bower to use https instead of git protocol ?
Or to specify explicitly the repository to fetch for a certain dependency ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to configure git to use the https protocol like this on your build machine:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my context I don't have access to this machine.